# Split digit and text by regexp

Tags: python, regex

I want to split digit and number into parts in a string by python with regexp.
For example :

```
string = "this1is2a3string4"
output = my_func(string)
```

The output will be `['this','1','is','2','my','3','string','4']`
I found some similar question but not what i want.
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split), just make sure you use a capturing group so the split characters are not removed.

Also I added in a check in the list comprehension to avoid empty strings when the first or last characters are matched by the regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "this1is2a3string4"
>>> [i for i in re.split(r'([0-9]+)', s) if i]
['this', '1', 'is', '2', 'a', '3', 'string', '4']
```

Comment: Glad to help, happy programming